# ifstream Class Resolution for getline

Tags: c++, class, std, ifstream

So I've was having some difficulty making the getline function actually compile in my code, and it was due to an incorrect call structure.

So I'm trying to understand how the call actually works.

My code includes:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
```

So from there I did the following in a function:

```
void getData(void)
{
    std:string lineIn;
    std::ifstream configFile(filePath.c_str(),std::ifstream::in);

    std::getline(configFile,lineIn);
}
```

Now what I don't get is why getline is resolved through the regular std library, even though it's a member of the ifstream class. From my understanding the ifstream class is a member of iostream.

Why does:

```
std::ifstream::getline
```

not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `std::getline` which takes a `std::string` is a "free function" in `namespace std` rather than a "member function" in `std::istream` is simple: the designers of C++ did not want to make the streams components depend on C++ strings.  The exact same reason why the `std::ifstream` constructor takes the filename as a `const char*` instead of a `std::string` - to avoid unnecessary inter-module dependencies.

Comment: @alphasierra: OK, that changes everything!  I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK, so if i understand that correctly getline can pull in data of any type? Also why are there listings in c++ references which have it entered as istring::getline()?

Comment: @alphasierra: you've got a typo: "istring" is not a thing.  And yes, getline can "pull in" (read) data of any type.

Comment: OK, I sporked that line from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ Is that an outdated reference?

Comment: @alphasierra: "istring" does not appear at the link you have posted.  Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is a separate function in namespace `std`, while [std::basic_istream::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) is a member of `std::basic_istream` of the same name.

Historically `std::basic_istream::getline` was limited to a `char*` buffer input much like [std::fgets()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) while `std::getline` works with `std::basic_string`s and lets you not to bother about buffer allocation etc.

Comment: I see. I guess I need to figure out how the various standard libraries are structured. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnZwinck correctly explained why historically `iostreams` library didn't use `string` library and vice versa (since `C++11` it's not completely true anymore, because std::ifstream & Co now [has constructor from std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)). Nowadays it makes sense to use `std::getline` or even [operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for input operations

Comment: I'll have to look into how input and output streams work in more detail. Thanks for your help!